# Split on period without removing the period punctuation once split - Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I have seen a lot of related questions to mine but I still can't seem to get my specific example to work. 
I have some data in a file which is several sentences strung together. I am trying to split the sentences into a list with each sentence being an element of the list. But when I split on a period followed by a space I lose the period in all the elements of my list (except the last one). 
I begin with this:

```
text = "This sentence. And this one. One more."
```

Desired output:

```
["This sentence.", "And this one.", "One more."]
```

Currently I am getting this by doing text.split('. "):

```
["This sentence","And this one","One more."]
```

Comment: you need lookahead/lookbehind

Comment: I tried this re.split(r'\.(?= )',text) but I have the same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use positive look behind:

```
import re
re.split(r'(?<=\.) ', text)
```

The above assumes your sentence always end with a period and a space (except the last sentence).
`(?<=\.)` is a positive look behind, so the regexp above will split on a space that is just after a dot, but it won't take dot into account when doing the substrings.

Comment: So since my text is biological I just realized that it sometimes splits on a name such as "C. elegans". So I was wondering how I could tell it to only split when there is a period, followed by a space followed by a capital letter. Sorry for the niche request. I tried this: re.split(r'(?<=\.) [A-Z]+', text) But am getting an error... Thank you!

Comment: I would require look behind + look ahead, so `re.split(r'(?<=\.) (?=[A-Z]))`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I struggle with the look behind/ahead. I appreciate your quick reply too!

Answer (score 1):

Given you stored the splitted list in a variable:

```
strList = text.split()
for line in strList:
   line.append('.')
strList[len(strList) - 1] = strList[len(strList) - 1][:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was trying to look for a one liner rather than having to go back and append the period but I will do this if no other solutions exist. I am just surprised that there is absolutely no way to tell python not to remove the delimiter....

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following and trim the leading whitespace.

```
[^\.]+\.
```

[REGEX demo](https://regex101.com/r/qS0vK3/1)

Answer (score 0):

this can also be done

```
[ i.group(0) for i in re.finditer('\S[^\.]+(\.|.$)', text)]
```

it matches any character other than dot till it reaches a dot or end of line